# Masking URL for window.print()

Tags: javascript, printing

So I've scoured the internet for a way to hide the url at the bottom of a page printed using window.print, and it seems the only way to do it is for the user to disable the option in their page settings.

Not ideal, I'm trying to hide the address to our serviceNOW instance from being printed on a form that will be given to our clients customers.

So with hiding it out of the question is there a way I can mask it to say something other than the actual url?

I'm not sure but I think solution 3 here is doing something like this
http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/424312/Can-anyone-help-me-to-hide-Header-Footer-and-Page

But I don't understand that at all.

Is it possible to fool the print dialog into thinking we are on a different page without actually redirecting?

btw I don't see it being useful for this solution but I cannot use jQuery (so many things would have been easier if I could) for some reason it will not work in our ServiceNOW instance.